# how to search for multiple field by text index from a database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In this product.model.js file i have my schema, my question is whenever i search anything let's say "Jeans"  then it should return all jeans that are written in product_name , product_code and product_description from all 3 fields

```
Here is product.model.js
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;


var ProductSchema   = new Schema({
product_name : {type: String, required: [true, 'Please give a product name'], unique: true}, //R U
product_code : {type: String, required: [true, 'Please give a product code'], unique: true},  //R U 
product_description : {type: String},    //"New Product for New Generation",
product_image : {type: String},//"default.jpg",
product_category : {type: String, required: [true, 'Please mention the category here']},//"Online", R 
product_price : {type: Number, required: [true, 'Please give a product price']},//700.00, R
product_tax : {type: Number, required: [true, 'Please write a product tax here']},//15, R 
product_status : Boolean, //true
product_current_stock : [],
product_min_quantity : {type: Number, min: [10, 'Too few products'], required: true},//10, R
product_unit : {type: String, required: [true, 'Please give a product unit']},//"Nos" R 
            });
ProductSchema.index({ product_name: "text" , product_code: "text", product_description: "text" });
            module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

---

```
and app.js
app.get('/product/search/:query', function(req, res){

var e = Product.find({ $text: { $search: req.params.query } },
         { score: { $meta: 'textScore' } }).
        sort({ score: { $meta: 'textScore'}}).
        exec(function(err, product)
        {
            if(err){
                    res.send(err)
                    }else{
                        res.status(200).json([{"Success": "true"}, {"Message": "Showing searched products"}, {"Total": "fail"}, {"Item": product} ]);
                        }
                    })
        })
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem you're having with the code above?

Comment: whenever i search anything let's say "Jeans" then it should return all jeans that are written in product_name , product_code and product_description from all 3 fields but it searches only those model that have written jeans in product_name not showing the other two i have also written jeans in product_description and t-shirt in product_name in that model  but it does not search this model basically i want to search from multiple fields like product_name product_code product_description and this code above seaches only from product_name ....